# How to pass Navigator or Void function as a parameter to a ListTile Widget -Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I'm Calling the Widget from my Home Page, and sending the required data as argument. like this:

```
     AppDrawerListTile(
                      title: 'Logout',     // title of the List Tile.
                      icon: Icons.logout, // icon for the list tile.
                      action: () {       // onTap action for ListTile - which is not working
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
                      }),
```

And here is the Custom Common List where, I'm getting the parameters and providing it to the ListTile.

```
class AppDrawerListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final Function action;
  const AppDrawerListTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.icon,
    required this.action,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      minVerticalPadding: 0,
      title: title.text.make().p0(),
      dense: true,
      // visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: -2, vertical: -3),
      // leading: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/mmsc_logo.png')),
      leading: Icon(icon),
      minLeadingWidth: 5,
      onTap: () => action, // Here I want the passed navigator function to work.
    );
  }
}
```

Everything is working here except the onTap Action Method,
I don't understand, should I declare the variable as Function or something else?

Comment: Change it to onTap: action, instead of onTap: () => action, you need to make action be the onTap function.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `( )` on `action` in `AppDrawerListTile` class, and the code should be

```
onTap: () => action(),
```

Full code

```
class AppDrawerListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final Function action;
  const AppDrawerListTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.icon,
    required this.action,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      minVerticalPadding: 0,
      title: title.text.make().p0(),
      dense: true,
      // visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: -2, vertical: -3),
      // leading: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/mmsc_logo.png')),
      leading: Icon(icon),
      minLeadingWidth: 5,
      onTap: () => action(), // Here I want the passed navigator function to work.
    );
  }
}
```

**Why?**

If there is no `()` sign it means that `onTap` calls anonymous function that returns `action` and does not call `action`.

```
() => action // returns action

// similar to
(){
 return action;
}
```

And if you add `()` sign it means that `onTap` calls anonymous function and the anonymous function calls `action` function.

```
() => action() // calls action

// similar to
(){
  action();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works smooth and proper <3

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a type into your widget and use it as a constructor parameter.

E.g.:

```
//here declare the type
typedef TypeNameYouWant = void Function();

class AppDrawerListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final TypeNameYouWant action; //here use the type declared
  const AppDrawerListTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.icon,
    required this.action,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListTile(
          minVerticalPadding: 0,
          title: title.text.make().p0(),
          dense: true,
      // visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: -2, vertical: -3),
      // leading: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/mmsc_logo.png')),
      leading: Icon(icon),
      minLeadingWidth: 5,
      onTap: () => action(), // Here you use your action param like a fn
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use VoidCallback instead of function

```
final VoidCallback action;
```