# How to get the onPressed response of a Button click form another screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a Button in a separate file. Trying to pass the 'onPressed' as a function, and get the response of the click from a different screen via a constructor.

## Button Widget

```
class FullWidthButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const FullWidthButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.buttonText,
    required this.onButtonPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String buttonText;
  final Function onButtonPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 1,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
            textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: onButtonPressed,
          child: Text(buttonText),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

## Implementation

```
FullWidthButton(
    buttonText: 'Sign Up',
    onButtonPressed: () => print('SignUp button is clicked!'),
)
```

---

## Error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead `final Function onButtonPressed;` try  `final Function() onButtonPressed;`

You pass already the function, but the **ElevatedButton** says that he want a Function(), not the "class" **Function**

Answer (score 1):

Try this `onPressed: ()=>onButtonPressed(),` on your `FullWidthButton` class.
You can see the reason on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72282460/11445944)